# Zoomfit to the selected polygon of WMS Layer using Leaflet Js

Tags: geoserver, cql-filter, leaflet-plugins, leaflet.wms

I have problem in **zoom fitting the selected polygon of WMS Layer**. For example, I have a World shapefile. I make a dropdown menu for country names, I did when I choose a country from dropdown menu only that polygon shown on map. But this selected polygon is not zoomed automatically.

When it is selected, I want it to zoom automatically. How can it be done?

I tried to implement `L.wmsImage` method of "**Leaflet-geoserver-request**" plugin for solving my problem, for the reference https://github.com/iamtekson/leaflet-geoserver-request.
But not get any result, following is my sample code:

```
var wmsImage = L.Geoserver.wmsImage("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/hindi_wrkspc/wms",{
    wmsLayers: ["hindi_wrkspc:country",],
    wmsCQL_FILTER: ["country_name =='India'" ],
    wmsStyle: ["hindi_wrkspc:country",],
    format: "image/png",
    wmsId: "wmsImage",
    width: 600,
    height: 600,
    transparent: true,
  });
```

When I run it, there is no error showing in console as well as not get any result.
How can I solve my problem?

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/55233/79 help?

Comment: Looking at https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html, it appears that the CQL filter doesn't handle any particular zooming, rather it just shows or hides data.  So what you have is expected behaviour.  If you want to zoom I think you'll need to hold the BBOX for the countries, and then supply that as the BBOX for the GetMap request

Comment: @nmtoken yes sir I read your suggested document "docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql" . For zooming selected polygon I used "Leaflet-geoserver-request" plugin, here is the link for plugin https://github.com/iamtekson/leaflet-geoserver-request. In this plugin L.geoserver.wmsImage() method is used for Zooming to desired location, implement it in my code but didn't get any success.

Comment: @Ian Turton -  Sir it is helpful. But I need to to do it as wms not as wfs. Your solution is done on wfs layer. I want solution for wms Layer. I want to automatically zoomfit the polygon of wms layer which is selected.

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: @Ian Turton- Okk Thanku Sir for your help.

Comment: Can anyone help me in implementing L.geoserver.wmsImage() method of "leaflet-geoserver-request" plugin.

Answer (score 1):

1- Why do you use L.geoserver.wmsImage instead of leaflet WMS?

https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html

2- You can use GetFeatureInfo WMS request at first and fetch the geom. Afterwards you can fit the bbox and wmsImage if you need the image.

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html?highlight=wms

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).